# How do I fix my SLD tile heat map when it comes up as dots?

Tags: geoserver, tiles, sld, heat-map

I am currently working on an SLD heat map on GeoServer that uses tiles.There is a point in each tile with the data. From far away, the heat map looks normal.

[image]

But up close it just becomes little dots within each tile

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: I guess It's not too late. You have to adjust your radius <ogc:Literal>radius</ogc:Literal> Try doubling the value